# Pointer to own data type in VBA

Tags: excel, pointers, types, vba

I want to make a pointer to my own data type in VBA and then use something like myDataType.vbString, but I'm doing it in the wrong way. I couldn't find the solution, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Type myDataType
    exampleString As String
    exampleInteger As Integer
End Type

Dim exampleType As myDataType
exampleType.exampleString = "Example"
exampleType.exampleInteger = 0

Dim examplePointer As LongPtr
examplePointer = VarPtr(exampleType)

' This is what I want to (or something like it)
' But it gives an error on the dot exampleString
If examplePointer.exampleString = "Example" Then
' Do something
Else: 'Do something else
End If
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (it's not possible in VBA as far as I understand you)

Comment: I am making a game (with 2 players). Sometimes I want to refer to the winner and sometimes to player 1. I thought it would be easy if I could say examplePointer = VarPtr(Player1) or else examplePointer = VarPtr(Player2), so the examplePointer alsways referers to the winner. So when I have to do something with Player1 I can say Player1.Name for example or when I have to do something with the winner i can say Winner.Name.

Comment: So why can't you just use another variable of `myDataType` and assign whichever existing one you want to it?

Comment: Because you have to win 3 games to win a match. And when I say Winner.GamesWon + 1 it will only change the GamesWon from the Winner variable and not the Player1 variable (if player1 wins a game). I have already found a way to do it without a pointer, but it was easier to do if I could use a pointer.

Comment: Then you have your answer below I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, the LongPtr data-type is not really a pointer, but a utility that represents the memory address of a variabe, in order to call *external* API's (DLL's) that require such pointers.

Therefore, in VBA you cannot *explicitly dereference a pointer* a la C or C++. However, pointers exist *implicitly*, similarly to Java: when you declare an *object variable*, you are imlicitly declaring a pointer. Example:

```
Dim sh as Excel.Worksheet '<~~ sh is a pointer, so far null because the object is not created yet.
Set sh = Application.Worksheets.Add '<~~ sh now points to the newly created worksheet object.
```

You can also create you own *Class*, but it needs to be in its own class module that has its name. For example, you can create a class module called `MyDataType`

```
' Class module MydataType
   Public exampleString As String
   Public exampleInteger As Integer
```

and you can instanciate it in another module

```
Dim exampleType As myDataType '<~~ null pointer declared
Set exampleType = new myDataType '<~~ now pointer is valid
exampleType.exampleString = "Example"
exampleType.exampleInteger = 0
```

Again, the LongPtr data type is just a utility to call external API's, not a real VBA data type. I hope this helps clarifying the concept.